# How to parse part of a cell containing x.x.x. and copy the data to another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, text

I have an excel file I want to parse the beginning of each cell in column D and copy and paste the numbers in cell(same row,column B) How do I parse the cells with numbers 0 through 9 and "." and copy just that value x.x.x.x to column B? There is no standard format of how many numbers and periods at the start of the cell in column D. It could be 1.3.4 or 1.3.4. or 1.3 ect...

```
===================================================================== 
'DIMENSIONING VARS AND PATHS
Dim Level As Range
Dim i, j, q(1 To 50) As Long
Dim numofchar As Long
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim PN As String
Dim HEADERrowcallout As Long
Dim LASTREQrowcallout As Long
Dim REQTEXTcolumncallout As String
Dim x As Long
Dim s As String
Dim count As Long
Dim Reqtext As Variant
Dim SectionText As Variant
'

'scanf(Input the correct row and column numbers). Used for determining start and endpoints of filtering files
HEADERrowcallout = InputBox("What row number are your headers in?")
LASTREQrowcallout = InputBox("What row number are your headers in?")
REQTEXTcolumncallout = InputBox("What is the column letter where ReqText is located? (A=1,B=2,D=4,ect...)")
'REQTYPEcolumncallout = InputBox("What is the column number from the left where the outline level is located? (A=1, B=2, ect...)")
'SECTIONcolumncallout = InputBox("What is the column number from the left where the outline level is located? (A=1, B=2, ect...)")
'


'stop screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'

'show gridlines
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
'

'Requirement Text to Section Maker --- Part (1)
'Part 1 filter string for the section number. (Numbers 1-10 & . until letters or space)
'Generate a string using the numbers and letters, ex [1.1.3.], cut & copy data to section column same row
For i = HEADERrowcallout + 1 To LASTREQrowcallout

    'Get length of active cell. This is max that copied cell will be

    LengthCell = Len(Cells(HEADERrowcallout + 1, REQTEXTcolumncallout))
    SectionText = (LengthActiveCell)
    Reqtext = (LengthActiveCell)

        'while count != length, scan each array position from 0 until array position value != 1-10 or .
        While x < LengthActiveCell
            Select Case Cells()
            Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "."
            Dim count As Long
            x = x + 1

        'If no more letters or .s, move to next cell
            x = LengthCell
    'if SectionText() = SectionText(0)

    'Keep going down ReqText column until specified end
    HEADERrowcallout = HEADERrowcallout + 1


End Sub
===========================
```

[Picture of Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEmkb.png)

Comment: In other words, you are just trying to pull the numbers out of the cells in coulmn D? Would this work instead? `=MID(D1,1,SEARCH(" ",D1)-1)`?

Comment: Why VBA? you can do it using formula only.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in formula. Also, The " " don't always occur after the periods or numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit: Now with comments explaining what the code does

Obviously you don't need the comments in your live version.

Paste the code below into a new Module, and then use it as a WorksheetFunction
(I took a guess as to what the function should be called). In any cell, enter `=ExtractOutline(<cell address>)`, where `<cell address>` is the cell from which you wish to extract the x.x.x. bit.

```
Function ExtractOutline(strInput As String)

    'Function iterates through the input string until we get to a
    'character which isn't one in "0123456789." Each character which is
    'one of these is added to the output as we go along

    Dim strOut As String        'The output we're building
    Dim intPos As Integer       'The position we've reached in the input
    Dim str1Char As String      'The character found at the current position

    intPos = 1     'We'll start at the first character
    str1Char = Mid(strInput, intPos, 1)       'Extract the intPos-th character, in this case, the 1st.

    While intPos <= Len(strInput) And WorksheetFunction.Find(str1Char, "0123456789." & str1Char) < 12

    'While
    'intPos <= Len(strInput) 
    'This makes sure we haven't iterated beyond the end of the input

    'AND
    'WorksheetFunction.Find(str1Char, "0123456789." & str1Char) < 12
    'Looks for the current character in "0123456789."
    'If it wasn't found we'd get an error (as output to the function)
    'To prevent that add current character to end of "0123456789."
    'Since "Find" returns the position, within the string,
    'and "01234567890." as 11 characters, we only match the right bit if it
    'is found before the 12th character

    'Add the character to the output
    strOut = strOut & Mid(strInput, intPos, 1)

    'Increment ready for next time round the loop
    intPos = intPos + 1
    'Get the next character to be checked
    str1Char = Mid(strInput, intPos, 1) 

    Wend

    ExtractOutline = strOut

End Function
```

Comment: I understand this code, but how do you pass the Cells text value as a string to the function?

Comment: If you put the code in a new module, you can then in any cell enter `=ExtractOutline(A1)` and if the cell A1 is one of your x.x. type strings, it will return just the relevant portion.

Comment: In the code, you initially take the first character and then are going from the first character (str1Char) as an argument and the second part is ""0123456789." & str1Char <12" I'm not quite clear on why you take the first character and how the arguments work together in the WorksheetFunction.Find.                                    Could you describe how this is working? I see you are parsing until you reach the end of the strInput but how is the 0123456789. the range and why is there and & str1Char <12 following it?

Comment: The `find` function returns to position in the string where the expression appears, and if not found returns an error. I had to avoid the error so to ensure its found i append the `str1Char`. The `<12` is because i don't want to continue if it's not in the first 11 characters. There may be better ways, but it's what i came up with first.

Comment: In case my preceding comment wasn't helpful, I've expanded on it in an edit to my answer ... with lots of extra comments in the code. If you use this and find it satisfactory, please mark my answer as accepted by way of a thank you (and to help other users who are looking for answers to similar questions).

Comment: Thanks for the help Steve. I appreciate it since I'm not familiar with some of these functions

Answer (score 0):

Or you can incorporate the following approach into your code...

```
Sub Alex()
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim RE As Object
Dim Match As Object

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("D2:D" & lr)
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

RE.Pattern = "([0-9]\.){1,}"

For Each cell In rng
If RE.test(cell.Value) = True Then
   Set Match = RE.Execute(cell.Value)
   cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = Left(Match(0), Len(Match(0)) - 1)
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Very close, but this wasn't greedy enough on my testing.

Comment: For `1.3.4` it grabs `1.3`, for `1.3` it grabs `1`.

Comment: But as per the sample data it should be 1.3.4. X.... or 1.3. X....  then it returns 1.3.4 and 1.3 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

You can see RegExp sample [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hdv65h/3)

*code*

```
Sub EddieBetts()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim X

Set rng1 = Range([d2], Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
X = rng1.Value2
Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegex.Pattern = "([0-9\.])+"

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    If objRegex.test(X(lngCnt, 1)) Then X(lngCnt, 1) = objRegex.Execute(X(lngCnt, 1))(0)
Next

rng1.Offset(0, -2).Value2 = X

End Sub
```